# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String ToBase64String(Byte[])

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, azure-sql-database

```
var pList = (from p in db.RTLS_PERSONDTLS
             where (lsdAts <= p.CREATED_TIME && 
             p.CREATED_TIME <= DateTime.Now)
             where p.OPERATION_TYPE == 1

             let pPhotoRow = (from q in db.Cloud_persons_images
                             where q.Image_name == p.PERSON_ID
                             where (lsdAts <= q.Createdtime && q.Createdtime <= DateTime.Now)
                             select q).FirstOrDefault()

                             let pExt = pPhotoRow.Img_ext
                             let photoBytes = pPhotoRow.Person_img

                             Let personPhoto =  new PersonPhotoInfo { PDATA = Convert.ToBase64String(photoBytes), PEXT = pExt }

            select new PersonListInfoDTO
             {
                MOB_NO = p.MOBILE_NO,
                ACTINACT = (int)p.ACTINACT,
                PHOTO = personPhoto
             }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

While **converting byte array into ToBase64String** i am getting exception as ***LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToBase64String(Byte[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.***  I am using sql Azure as my back-end storage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method

Comment: I had tried many of the possible solutions which are provided in internet for this exception, but i did't get solution for my problem.. thanks for the links

Comment: The solution is always the one and same - double projection. First in anonymous types to get the raw data, then `AsEnumerable()` and the actual projection where you can use any CLR methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one

```
var pList =from item in (from p in db.RTLS_PERSONDTLS
             where (lsdAts <= p.CREATED_TIME && 
             p.CREATED_TIME <= DateTime.Now)
             where p.OPERATION_TYPE == 1

             let pPhotoRow = (from q in db.Cloud_persons_images
                             where q.Image_name == p.PERSON_ID
                             where (lsdAts <= q.Createdtime && q.Createdtime <= DateTime.Now)
                             select q).FirstOrDefault()
                          select new {
                               p.MOBILE_NO,
                               p.ACTINACT,
                               Img_ext= pPhotoRow.Img_ext,
                               photoBytes=pPhotoRow.Person_img
                               }).ToList())                             )

            select new PersonListInfoDTO
             {
                MOB_NO = item.MOBILE_NO,
                ACTINACT = (int)item.ACTINACT,
                PHOTO = new PersonPhotoInfo { PDATA = Convert.ToBase64String(item.photoBytes), PEXT = pExt }
             }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah the idea worked for me with little modifications, modifications are 1.AsNoTracking() is removed on item collection.   2. PEXT = pExt is changed to PEXT = item.Img_ext. Now its working fine thank u

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Linq will translate your query into sql and the query generated will contain a call to the Convert.ToBase64String method, of which sql does not know about.
You can do a ToList() to load the object from the database into the memory and then apply the Convert.ToBase64String method

```
var pList = (from item in (from p in db.RTLS_PERSONDTLS
         where (lsdAts <= p.CREATED_TIME && 
         p.CREATED_TIME <= DateTime.Now)
         where p.OPERATION_TYPE == 1

         let pPhotoRow = (from q in db.Cloud_persons_images
                         where q.Image_name == p.PERSON_ID
                         where (lsdAts <= q.Createdtime && q.Createdtime <= DateTime.Now)
                         select q).FirstOrDefault())
                      select new {
                           p.MOBILE_NO,
                           p.ACTINACT,
                           Img_ext= pPhotoRow.Img_ext,
                           photoBytes=pPhotoRow.Person_img
                           }).ToList()
        .Select(t=> new PersonListInfoDTO
         {
            MOB_NO = item.MOBILE_NO,
            ACTINACT = (int)item.ACTINACT,
            PHOTO = new PersonPhotoInfo { PDATA = Convert.ToBase64String(item.photoBytes), PEXT = pExt }
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: This idea also worked. But i cant able to mark it as answer stack overflow does not allowing me to accept two answers at a time